# Debug Kotlin Symbol Processing (KSP)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-symbol-processing

How to debug KSP using Idea and Gradle?

Running `build` task from IDE in debug mode does not attach IDE to the process.

Is there any command-line way to make the processor wait until IDE attach to thte process?

(I'm using KSP `1.5.31-1.0.0`)

Answer (score 6):

`./gradlew :sample:build --no-daemon -Dorg.gradle.debug=true -Dkotlin.compiler.execution.strategy=in-process`

If debugging without daemon is too slow (it has to start jvm everytime), `./gradlew  -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options="-Xdebug,-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket\,address=8765\,server=y\,suspend=n" ...` and attach to the KotlinCompileDaemon process in the debugger.

More info here: https://github.com/google/ksp/issues/31

Comment: Thank you for the response. I saw that conversation and none of those commands work for me. The first one just hangs, the second does not wait for a debugger to attach.

Comment: I also uses unit test from Idea with a breakpoint and the 2 options in Idea related to gradle debug and compiler in process.